# How can we build a polymer from a monomer in Avogadro?

Tags: software, molecular-modeling, avogadro

I have been trying to reproduce a geometry optimization from a research paper, where it was done by Avogadro.

However, I cannot find the option for building a polymer from a monomer. I am using Avogadro 2.

Comment: Welcome to our new community! Have you reproduced the result with the older version of Avogadro? Or is it simply that you don't know how to build a polymer from a monomer, regardless of the software's version?

Comment: I don't know how to build a polymer from monomer in Avogadro

Comment: So when you said "but now in Avogadro 2" and implied that the problem was with the new version, you really meant that you simply don't know how to do it in either version, it seems. I'll edit your question to make it more clear.

Comment: One way that I can think of: Select an atom where you wish to attach the next monomer, and go to Build->Insert->Fragment->Choose your monomer. If it's unavailable in the list, you can save your custom fragments in Avogadro's library folder at your installed software location.

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but can you update us now that it has been 6+ months since you asked this question? Have you found the answer? Are you still actively in need of an answer? Was the comment by @KavyaMrudula helpful?